# Get the PCM data of the songs currently playing in the android phone

Tags: android, pcm, decoder

I am planning to fetch the decoded PCM data of a currently playing
song in the android phone. Can we do it from the application layer?
Meanwhile it would be really helpful if any one of you could suggest
me an audio decoder in java.

Regards
Albin

Answer (score 3):

Try out this. It will help you to get PCM data for currently playing song :

```
mVisualizer = new Visualizer(mPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
        mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);

    Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener captureListener = new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
                int samplingRate)
        {
            //PCM DATA 
        }

        @Override
        public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
                int samplingRate)
        {

        }
    };

    mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(captureListener,
            Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, false);

    // Enabled Visualizer and disable when we're done with the stream
    mVisualizer.setEnabled(true);
    mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
        {
            mVisualizer.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```